# Limitation of roles and users in snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, roles

is there any limitation on creating custom roles and users in snowflake?

As per my use case i want to create multiple user based on different role. Each user needs to create one role and each role can be parent of many roles.

So I wanted to understand the limitation of no. of roles and users in snowflake.

Answer (score 1):

There is no hard limit on the number of users or roles. There can be a soft limit, which can be adjusted if necessary (your account manager or support can help with getting it adjusted).

Comment: Can you plz help on soft limit part

Comment: Is there anyway to find this soft limit so that we can decide our architecture. Please help

Comment: Reach out to your account manager or open a support request and they will help you out